# How to initialize a dynamic array in java?

Tags: java, dynamic-arrays

If I have a class that needs to return an array of strings of variable dimension (and that dimension could only be determined upon running some method of the class), how do I declare the dynamic array in my class' constructor?

If the question wasn't clear enough,

in php we could simply declare an array of strings as `$my_string_array = array();`
and add elements to it by `$my_string_array[] = "New value";`

What is the above code equivalent then in java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will want to look into the `java.util package`, specifically the `ArrayList` class. It has methods such as `.add() .remove() .indexof() .contains() .toArray()`, and more.

Comment: Just to be precise, it's in `java.util` (along with all other collection classes). `java.util.Collections` (with uppercase C) is a utility class, not a package.

Comment: as a follow up question, is it also possible to create string indexes [e.g.: $my_string_array["property"] ]?

Comment: @lock you should look into java's Map interface and HashMap class to create the equivalent of an associative array (array with string indices). Hashmaps can have any type of object as the key (index).If you need to preserve insertion order, or be able to work with integer position indices look into the LinkedHashMap class.

Answer (score 7):

Plain java arrays (ie `String[] strings`) cannot be resized dynamically; when you're out of room but you still want to add elements to your array, you need to create a bigger one and copy the existing array into its first `n` positions.

Fortunately, there are `java.util.List` implementations that do this work for you. Both `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.Vector` are implemented using arrays.

But then, do you really care if the strings happen to be stored internally in an array, or do you just need a collection that will let you keep adding items without worrying about running out of room? If the latter, then you can pick any of the several general purpose `List` implementations out there. Most of the time the choices are:

- `ArrayList` - basic array based implementation, not synchronized
- `Vector` - synchronized, array based implementation
- `LinkedList` - Doubly linked list implementation, faster for inserting items in the middle of a list

Do you expect your list to have duplicate items? If duplicate items should never exist for your use case, then you should prefer a `java.util.Set`. Sets are guaranteed to not contain duplicate items. A good general-purpose set implementation is `java.util.HashSet`.

**Answer to follow-up question**

To access strings using an index similar to `$my_string_array["property"]`, you need to put them in a `Map<String, String>`, also in the `java.util` package. A good general-purpose map implementation is `HashMap`.

Once you've created your map,

- Use `map.put("key", "string")` to add strings
- Use `map.get("key")` to access a string by its key.

Note that `java.util.Map` cannot contain duplicate keys. If you call `put` consecutively with the same key, only the value set in the latest call will remain, the earlier ones will be lost. But I'd guess this is also the behavior for PHP associative arrays, so it shouldn't be a surprise.

Answer (score 6):

Create a [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead.

```
List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
l.add("foo");
l.add("bar");
```

Comment: For most use cases an array list is a better choice, but thats why it is always good to declare the variable using interfaces opposed to classes (so its easy to change the underlying implementation).

Answer (score 1):

No dynamic array in java, length of array is fixed.
Similar structure is `ArrayList`, a real array is implemented underlying it. 
See the name **Array**List :)